# Add item to combobox from multiple range with criteria from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, range

I have a combobox on a userform that i need to add values from a fixed range (With criteria), but i need it to do this across 4 sheets

The Sheets are "WRS P1", "WRS P2", "WRS P3" and "WRS P4"
Column A has a range of Dates (A8:A32) (This range has a formula in all cells within range, but only some may actually be populated with a value)
I need these dates added to the Combobox when the cell in column E is empty
The dates in column A will fill the above range in WRS P1 first, then once the range is full, it will flow to WRS P2 in the same range, then to WRS P3 and so on

I need some code to cycle through the range in the first sheet (WRS P1),
Once the code reaches an empty cell in column A (Within the range) then the code can stop

I have code to do this on 1 sheet, but i cannot seem to get it to continue looking on the next sheet

This is the code i currently have:

Any assitance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim rngEmpD As Range
Dim rngListD As Range
Dim strSelectedD As String
Dim LastRowD As Long

            strSelectedD = ""
          
            LastRowD = Worksheets("WRS P1").Range("A8:A32").Find("", , xlValues, , , xlNext, , , False).Row
 
           Set rngListD = Worksheets("WRS P1").Range("E8:E" & LastRowD - 1)
 
           For Each rngEmpD In rngListD
 
                 If rngEmpD.Value = strSelectedD Then
 
                      Me.ComboBox1.AddItem rngEmpD.Offset(, -3)
                    
 
                 End If
 
           Next rngEmpD
```

Comment: Do you want processing only the ranges between rows 8:32? If not, is this a minimum range and is it possible to also be data bellow and you need the last row having a value?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru
There is data both above and below this range, which is why i need to have it specifically reference A8:A32

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted? I tried keeping your way of dealing with the last row, even if it looked strange and not understood its reason, but if you need only the range referenced by A8:A32, what is to be calculated about the last row?  Why not simple 8:32 for all columns? Am I missing something?

Comment: because not all cells in that row would have a value
In the first sheet, there is a formula within that range that will result in a date if conditions are met, (Based on current date) and so as time goes, the dates will populate
Once all cells in the first sheet within that range have a date, column A in second sheet will start filling with dates. Once the second sheet for that range is full, it will flow to the 3rd sheet and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with the code below.

We basically add the 4 sheets to an array and loop through the array to get the sheet names. Then we loop through each row in each sheet to add the items to the combobox.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant

arr = Array("WRS P1", "WRS P2", "WRS P3", "WRS P4")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    With Sheets(arr(i))
        For j = 8 To 32
            If .Range("B” & j).Value = "" Then Exit For
            If .Range("E" & j).Value = "" Then
                Me.ComboBox1.AddItem .Range("B" & j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Unfortunately the script does not work.
As there is data in column A above and below the range specified, i need the code to specifically only reference A8:A32
When i fix this code to specifically reference this range, it has ah error "Subscript out of range" occurring at ```With Sheets(arr(i)) ```

Comment: Where does it fail for you?

Comment: I've updated it. It will specifically loop through rows 8 to 32, first checking if the column A row is blank, and if it is, moves on to the next sheet. This way we remove dealing with an error of the `.Find` not finding anything should all rows 8 to 32 be filled. I also changed the `For i`. I'm not sure why you're getting that error. Does it happen on the first pass of it or on another one? You sure the sheet names are correct?

Comment: Also I tested the sheets part using those exact sheet names and worked for me.

Comment: this time there is no error, but has not added anything to the combobox (I have checked that there should have been items added)

Comment: If you try stepping through the code with F8 does it actually go into the combobox line? That doesn't really make any sense that it wouldn't add anything.

Comment: One issue that was pointed out is i was referencing the wrong column, should have been B (Im so sorry!)
When i changed the column it worked great! Thank you :)

Comment: So I understood. I have updated it to reflect that. Is all of it column B or just the stuff to go into the combobox? (AKA is column A used at all for this?)

Comment: column A is not used, it all should be B, apologies for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub fillCombo()
  Dim LastRow As Long, arrSh, El, arrE, i As Long

       arrSh = Split("WRS P1,WRS P2,WRS P3,WRS P4", ",")
       For Each El In arrSh
            LastRow = Worksheets(El).Range("A8:A32").Find("", , xlValues, , , xlNext, , , False).row
 
           arrE = Worksheets(El).Range("A8:E" & LastRow - 1).Value 'to make the iteration faster
           For i = 1 To UBound(arrE)
                If arrE(i, 5) = "" Then Me.ComboBox1.AddItem arrE(i, 2)
           Next i
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error at the 4th line of your code
"For Each may only iterate over a collection object or an array"

Comment: @Natalie Hunt Which is this 4th line? `arrSh = Split("WRS P1,WRS P2,WRS P3,WRS P4", ",")`. It shouldn't raise any error? Do you count without empty rows? Is it `For Each El In arrSh`? It cannot raise an error neither. The iteration take place between the array elements. Did you use the code **as it is**, or tried some modifications?

Comment: @Natalie Hunt If not anything confidential, can you share the workbook you use? The above code cannot raise such an error it is used as it is, I'm afraid...

Comment: it was the for each line, i tried again and seems to have no error, but has not added anything to the combobox

Comment: @Natalie Hunt It is not possible to try it in the same way and one  time to have an error and next one not... But, do you say that **your code returns correctly for one sheet**? If yes, it returns from B:B column (`rngEmpD.Offset(, -3)`). Is this what you want in fact? I tried following your need as **it was explained in words**. Should I follow your code, too? I will adapt it to return from B:B, as yours... Please, test it and send some feedback. But you did not say anything about sharing the workbook. I will immediately show you what problem you have... If not sharing, please place a picture

Comment: @Natalie Hunt I adapted the code to return as yours. But, in order to better understand your question, which I must confess looks strange, please edit your question and put there a picture of such a sheet to be processed. Is the workbook you need processing the active one?

Comment: The range is so small, why not just check every cell on column A on every sheet until value = "". And additem if corresponding E is empty?

Comment: I cannot share the whole workbook as it does have sensitive data, but i will try and make a 'dummy' version to post

Comment: @Gokhan Aycan And what difference will that make? I have the habit to make my code as fast as possible. I do not know if the range in discussion is just an example to receive an answer and use the solution for the real one.... Anyhow, your suggestion will not change anything regarding the code logic. Now, I am starting to ask myself if the OP really knows what she wants...

Comment: @Natalie Hunt No problem with me. Do not bother to build a dummy one, you should be focusing on better explain your need against your real workbook. Is it also o problem to post a picture of such a sheet?

Comment: ahh, im an idiot! you are right, it should be B!!
Your code worked for the first sheet, but i think you are right in that the code i had for finding the last row may be causing the issue
I used this to get the range for the code to look at

Comment: @FaneDuru Apparantly, nothing for you or me. But OP will follow it easier and possibly modify it better without help. Your approach is good, no issue there. I follow your comments and answers for other questions as well. :)

Comment: @Natalie Hunt Now, since we started understanding each other, I will try to make some statements and you will comment them: 1. Your way of calculating the last row will return **the first empty cell in the "A8:A32" range**. Is that what what you want? 2. All the other sheets have the same structure?  If  yes, the above code should work...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I do know what i want to achieve, however my Knowledge of VBA may be such that i have not explained clearly enough
I am sorry you feel you have wasted your time, but i thank you for your contribution anyway :)

Comment: @Natalie Hunt If **what you wanted to achieve** was only in your head, I can admit the statement. Otherwise, not. And it is very possible to not explain in the best way, and not something to be accused, but **your feedback after telling you what may not happen and what will be good for you to do**, was not on my taste at all. If you cannot help us to help you, the helping process is much more longer than it should and I do not like that.